# How do I center my navigation bar on my webpage?

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

I cant manage to center my navigation bar. I am really new to web design and any help would be much appreciated. [Here is the navigation bar.](http://teaminnova.net)

Comment: Bilbo post your css here.What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You have to show us some sort of effort in solving the problem. StackOverflow isn't a 'code-order' website. [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)? What possible solutions do you think there are? Have you tried looking around for this answer anywhere else?

Comment: by setting `margin: 0 auto;` this div will auto center, if it gives you trouble add `display: inline-block;` to the div, obviously the div's width has to be less than the page's width.. these are CSS basics, try reading more tutorials online

Answer (score 3):

Change the rules for `ul` to:

```
ul#menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
    width: 705px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks the bar is centered but now when i try to hover over the members tab it all moves around and glitches everywhere any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @Bilbo - Try changing the `ul` to `ul#menu`.

Comment: It is better than before but the last tab always manages to go underneath the tab before it when I hover over members

Answer (score 0):

```
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position: absolute;
    left:25%;
    right:25%;
}
```

Or you can set your left right as per your choice .